# Send Kubernetes pod's logs to Splunk

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, splunk, fluentd, amazon-eks

I am using Amazon EKS and I have a server (consider it as X ) which is connected to the control node using kubectl.

I am able to get the pod logs from the server X by running the following command.
 kubectl logs -f podname -n=namespace

Now my goal is to send these pod logs to Splunk for which I am using [splunk-connect-for-kubernetes](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes)

But as per the configurations of values.yaml file, kubernetes logs are forwarded to the Splunk instead of the pod logs.

I would specifically like to send the pod logs i.e. my application logs to the Splunk. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: As per the `splunk-connect-for-kubernetes` documentation `Splunk Connect for Kubenetes also supports importing and searching your container logs on AWS ECS and AWS Fargate using firelens.` Did you validate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the option you have is to make use of [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/), [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/) combination to read and send to splunk.

Comment: Is there any documentation available which shows the whole process? I don't see any documentation on internet which shows the steps for my requirement.

Comment: You can find lot online. Basically you will be having fluentbit as ds in all nodes and one fluentd pod to send the logs to splunk.