# Splunk Kubernetes example

Tags: kubernetes, splunk, fluentd, fluent-bit

I found this entry
[Send Kubernetes pod's logs to Splunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129598/send-kubernetes-pods-logs-to-splunk)

I was wondering if anyone had a front-to-back example (blog, video, etc.).

I'm used to Kubernetes, but not used to Splunk. I want to deploy something like the [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/) with [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) solution or [Splunk Connect for Kubnernetes](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes). I've done this with other solutions pretty easily (they usually have something simple to deploy into K8s), but working with Splunk is giving me problems.

I'm covering three scenarios here:

1. Some things log only to stdout, which fluentbit/fluentd should handle
2. Some things log only to file
3. I'd like to collect all the Kubernetes events

Right now I'm mostly worried about sceario 1, but I have no control over the pods/containers, the configuration, etc. I have to find a way to do that without changing the Helm charts that are being used for deployment. I put in change requests for #2 to at least get the data into stdout, but that's another battle.

I've tried a bunch of things (links below) but it's just not behaving for me. I was hoping to follow a tutorial step-by-step to get a POC done and then get in an customize it further.

Some stuff I've been reading/watching:

- **Most useful one so far:** [Send Logs to Splunk on Kubernetes using Splunk Forwarder](https://computingforgeeks.com/send-logs-to-splunk-using-splunk-forwarder/) - gets me to the point where I understand I can use the [splunk/universalforwarder:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/universalforwarder) image to get logs flowing to my Splunk instance
- **Deploy Splunk Enterprise on Kubernetes**: [1](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/platform/deploy-splunk-enterprise-on-kubernetes-splunk-connect-for-kubernetes-and-splunk-insights-for-containers-beta-part-1.html)/[2](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/platform/deploy-splunk-enterprise-on-kubernetes-splunk-connect-for-kubernetes-and-splunk-insights-for-containers-beta-part-2.html)/[3](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/it/deploy-splunk-enterprise-on-kubernetes-splunk-connect-for-kubernetes-and-splunk-insights-for-containers-beta-part-3.html) - which seemed to get me running my own host and local data just fine, but not what I need
- **Videos from Splunk User Groups**: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZgGXk2a5d4)/[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2NH1K8Lh8s) - again, got Splunk running but doesn't give insight on forwarding data from Kuberenetes
- **Splunk Forum Posts**: [1](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/How-to-index-Kubernetes-STDOUT-data-in-Splunk/m-p/222592) - led me to the next one
- **Splunk Official Git Hub Projects:** [Splunk Connect for Kubnernetes](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes) - which I'm just not following for some reason ... but this seems like what I really should be using here

I really think I just need something with more verbose, step-by-step instructions written so a toddler can follow them.

I am going to try [Splunk Connect for Kubnernetes](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes) from scratch again to see if I can figure it out; however - any links to tutorials would be very helpful.

Unfortunately I don't have time to learn Splunk inside-and-out, nor budget to get someone else in to do this.